# Why should we use HTTPS?

Tags: https

I have learned a little about https, but was not clear why it is needed.

What if I encrypt the data using the most powerful algorithms like RSA instead of sending through a HTTPS zone? Can someone explain with a few reasons why we need https?

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately this question is not suited to the Q&A format and will probably be deleted. The best questions are ones with definite answers.  This is a good resource for your question: http://bit.ly/Ro3TfC

Comment: In this case, I'd suggest you keep reading and accept the standard. This is not something someone with limited experience should be questioning.

Comment: @chris..asking doubts and questioning is entirely different..Hope this is a site where people shares the ideas and knowledge..If u cant answer a question,please keep away.dont underestimate others like this. asking doubts is not a fault in my perspective..

Answer (score 1):

On the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https) it says

> Technically, it is not a protocol in itself; rather, it is the result
>   of simply layering the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) on top of
>   the SSL/TLS protocol

On the [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) article on Wikipeida,

> TLS and SSL encrypt the segments of network connections at the
>   Application Layer for the Transport Layer, using asymmetric
>   cryptography for key exchange, symmetric encryption for
>   confidentiality, and message authentication codes for message
>   integrity.

So the key exchange **does** use [asymmetric cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) and RSA is an asymmetric cryptography algorithm.

After key exchange has been performed in a secure manner further communication can be done through symmetric cryptographic algorithms. The reasoning behind using both symmetric and asymmetric algorithms can be found [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/why-do-we-need-asymmetric-algorithms-for-key-exchange).

Answer (score 0):

> What if I encrypt the data using the most powerful algorithms like RSA
>   instead of sending through a HTTPS zone?

You will have to implement all by yourself, i.e. reinvent the wheel. HTTPS is by default supported in every browser.

> Can someone explain with a few reasons why we need https?

Secure communication that is widely supported. If you have in the middle of communication someone with sniffer tool like Wireshark, he/she will be able to see all packets that you and your peer exchange. Try to catch the HTTPS communication, you won't be able to see anything meaningful in the body of the request.

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed encrypt the data by yourself, but you will face a big problem: The encrypting code must be available on the server as well as on the client (normally the browser).

Implementing the encryption on the server can be done securely. On the client side you can either install a software (plugin), or you can send JavaScript to the client. The problem is: **how do you get the encrypting code to the client?** Everybody evesdropping, will get the javascript code as well, so he can do the same things as the client will be able to do.

Instead of forcing the user to install a plugin, you can use the built-in support for SSL, every browser understands this protocol already. You could think of it, as an already installed plugin for encryption.

Comment: actually i've been working with Rijndaels algorithm for encrypting connections between to applications written in vb.net, and I have devised (so far only in idea stage) a method that through several steps shares the keys with host/client, jumbles, creates new keys, encrypts, shares, and jumbles again to use two completely different sets of keys, and finish with one set on both host & client that are the same (the last share is encrypted, so the hacker can't decrypt the new keys to decrypt any further comunication). so theoretically it can be achieved similarly to this, but i recommend HTTPS

Comment: @Sylvester - So you have the situation of the user installing a software, this allows to implement encryption yourself. I'm not the one praying, never to delve into this matter, but as you pointed out, you spent a lot of time studying the problems, and that is an absolute must then. And yes - it's ways easier and safer to use an existing implementation, especially if it is so widely used as SSL.

Comment: yes, like i said HTTPS is the best option, but the two users running the same application means the encryption method is the same, so the other end can predict what the key will be (it's received the other end's key, it knows its own key, it knows how it jumbles the two keys together to form a new one unknown to the hacker; so it just performs the same task to determine what the other end will wind up with) theoretically, you can use this same technique in a website but as mentioned, just stick with normal https